# Host WCF service from local network to internet

Tags: wcf

I have created one WCF service using nettcp binding and one client in my local network domain. client can connect that host service on network domain through IP address. Now I want to access that WCF service from outside my local network domain. My PC is connected with internet but not having live IP address. How can I make settings like my service is accessible from internet ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to [forward the port](http://portforward.com/) you're using (the default net.tcp port is 808 as mentioned by @the_ajp) towards the machine that's hosting the service. This can be configured in your router.

Comment: And open port 808 in your firewall.

Comment: Can you please explain me in details about how to forward port ?

Comment: Can you please click the link under "forward the port"?